# Need Suggestion for Newsletter implementation

Tags: java, .net, email, newsletter, email-spam

I want to ask about newsletter implementation.

We want to develop web application, the content for this website can be  subscribe by people based on subscription membership. `Gold, Premium and Silver`. 
Our estimation there are `700 Gold` Subscribers, `500 Premium` Subscribers, and `300 Silver` subscribers. Total is 1500 subscribers. The newsletter will be sent every day in the morning to each subscriber via email. We will have our own email server for mail delivery, and may be It will developed using Java and .NET .

My Question are :

1. Can we only have separate service installed in our server, let say windows service or linux service to send newsletter for each subscribers ?
2. I will `iterate each subscribers and send the newsletter one by one based on subscription type`. is there something issue ?
3. Do I need `third party mail manager` such as Mailman or mailchimp ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not tag your question with `C#`, `Java`, `asp.net`, and `spring` all at once when it in fact involves none of those topics.(Instead you could try there is `email` and `sendmail` and `e-mail integration`...)

Comment: Silverpop also one more option to implement.

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes, this is perfectly doable
2. How do you handle [bounces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message)? How do you handle unsubscriptions? How do you handle retries but not send one message repeatedly?
3. Mailchimp is nice and it will be free for your volumes (up to 2000 subscribers, I believe). If you want something more low-level, I'd suggest going with Postmark, SendGrid or Amazon SES.

Comment: Just a minor. The answer to case 1 depends on what ISP they have, and what contract they have. Some will not allow users to have mail servers (due to spam)